# The number of integer pairs so that $f(x,y) = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, divisibility

Let $f(x,y) = 4x^2 -3xy -2y + 1 $ . Find $(x , y)$ so that $x , y \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $f(x,y) = 0 $  . I've tried many numbers and got some answers but it's not the solution !

Comment: $3x+2$ will divide $$4x^2+1$$ 
iff $3x+2$ will divide $$3(4x^2+1)=4x(3x+2)+3-8x$$

$3x+2$ will divide $3-8x$  iff $3x+2$ will divide $$3(3-8x)=25-8(3x+2)$$

so, $3x+2$ needs to divide $25$

Comment: Very nice , Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=4x^2 -3xy -2y + 1$$

$$y=\frac{4x^2+1}{3x+2},~~ 3x+2\ne 0$$

$$3y=\frac{12x^2+3}{3x+2}=4x-\frac{8x-3}{3x+2}=4x-2-\frac{2x-7}{3x+2}$$

$$3(-3y+4x-2)=\frac{6x-21}{3x+2}=2+\frac{-25}{3x+2}$$

$$9y-12x+8=\frac{25}{3x+2}$$

$$(9y-12x+8)(3x+2)=25$$

$$k(3x+2)=25$$

$$3x+2=-25,-5,-1,1,5,25$$

Try

$$
\begin{align}
& 3x+2=-25,~~~k=-1,~~~~x=-9,~~~~y=-13 \\
& 3x+2=-5,~~~~~k=-5,~~~~x=\text{bad}\\
&3x+2=-1,~~~~k=-25,~~~~x=-1,~~~~y=-5\\
&3x+2=+1,~~~~k=25,~~~~~~x=\text{bad}\\
&3x+2=+5,~~~~~k=+5,~~~~x=1,~~~~y=1\\
&3x+2=25,~~~~~~k=+1,~~~~x=\text{bad}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 4x^2-3xy-2y+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 4x^2-3xy-y^2+y^2-2y+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 4x^2-4xy+xy-y^2+(y-1)^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (4x-y)(x-y)+(y-1)^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (4x-y)(x-y)+(y-1)^2=0$$

Since $(y-1)^2 \ge 0$, so we can conclude that $(4x-y)(x-y)$ must be negative for $f(x,y)=0$ to hold.

Which means, either $4x-y \le 0$ and $x+y \ge 0$; OR 
 $x+y \le 0$ and $4x-y \ge 0$.

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(-9,-13\right)$,$\left(-1,-5\right)$,$\left(1,1\right)$. Three pairs.